# Do async work to set properties of an object inside a forEach and then return the object once all async work is done

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

I'm trying to write some code that allows me to iterate over an array and perform some async work for each element in the array. The idea is to perform async work, get a value from it and then set an object's property to that value, then move onto the next. Once it's all finished I want to return the resultant object.

The problem is that my async code is not working properly, the uninitialised variable is being returned before any of the async code is being ran. I'm not entirely sure the await before the forEach is doing anything either.

```
generate(): Promise<Properties>{
        return new Promise<Properties>(async resolve => {
            let columns = this._propertyDefinitionRepo.columnNames;
            let properties: Properties;
            await columns.map(async columnName => {
                return new Promise<void>(async resolve => {
                    let distinctValues = await this.doAsyncWork(columnName);
                    properties[this.columnNameToPropertyName(columnName)] = 
                         this.buildPropertyDefinition(columnName, distinctValues);
                    resolve();
                })
            });
            resolve(properties);
        })
    }
```

Comment: This is Typescript, no?  You may wish to add that tag.

Comment: Yes it is, added. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `.map()` here, as that will execute all the callbacks without waiting for each to represent a promise that resolved.

Instead use a plain `for` loop, so the `await` happens in the context of the outside function context.

Finally, you are using a promise constructor callback antipattern. Don't use `new Promise` when you already have a promise at hand.

So:

```
async generate(): Promise<MonitorProperties>{
    let columns = this._propertyDefinitionRepo.columnNames;
    let properties: Properties;
    for (let columnName of columns) {
        let distinctValues = await this.doAsyncWork(columnName);
        properties[this.columnNameToPropertyName(columnName)] = 
                 this.buildPropertyDefinition(columnName, distinctValues);
    }
    return properties;
}
```